# Auto-renewable subscription issue in iOS 8 Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

When I used non-consumable in-app purchase product for testing after purchased it will give proper result that is You are already purchased but in Auto-renewable subscription it will always ask for purchase for the same user and for the same product. How to resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read apple's documentation to test Auto renewable subscriptions

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Answer (score 0):

A Side Note: In the consumable case it is prohibited that you forward the user to the store if he/she already purchased the item. Unless, he/she reinstalled the app. or installed it on a different device that didn't used to purchase the item in the first place.

[Auto-renewale here is your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086612/in-app-purchase-multiple-auto-renewing-subscriptions-having-different-durations)

Comment: I don't know what I doing wrong I follow apple documentation and above link. But my problem is still that once I buy the product it will again ask me for purchase in Auto-renewable subscription.